# How can I stretch a marquee plugin to 100% width?

Tags: html, css, width, marquee

I have something like a marquee on my website and I can't stretch it to 100% width. I guess I am missing something for sure.
Here you are the HTML:

```
<div id="marquee">
    <div>
      <span>programmation festival des blocs 6/1</span>
      <span>programmation festival des blocs 6/1</span>
      <span>programmation festival des blocs 6/1</span>
      <span>programmation festival des blocs 6/1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here you are the jsfiddle with CSS as well: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y674tbwz/1/)

Thank you very much for you help!

Marco

Comment: What your fiddle shows seems to go over the whole width already …? (Maybe you just want to eliminate the default margin applied to body as well?)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `margin` of the body

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y674tbwz/3/)